# Bigquery-Spark Connector:

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

While writing data to Bigquery using the spark bigquery connector. Am running into this issue. If the data is read from a file, the connector writes the data to the bigquery table. But only when the data is read from a Cassandra table it is throwing the above error.
I check the types after reading a file and after reading from Cassandra. Both point to spark.sql.Dataframe type correctly.

```
19/05/31 10:02:32 INFO com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryHelper: No import schema provided, auto detecting schema.
19/05/31 10:02:39 ERROR org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter: Aborting job job_20190531100218_0006.
java.io.IOException: Error during BigQuery job execution: {"location":"query","message":"Schema has no fields. Table: orders_output_e4c96db3_d224_46ca_aef7_5b3fd0f19162_source","reason":"invalidQuery"}
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryUtils.waitForJobCompletion(BigQueryUtils.java:108)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryHelper.importFromGcs(BigQueryHelper.java:234)
        at com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.IndirectBigQueryOutputCommitter.commitJob(IndirectBigQueryOutputCommitter.java:73)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1083)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1081)
        at com.hm.CassandraBigquery$.main(CassandraBigquery.scala:41)
        at com.hm.CassandraBigquery.main(CassandraBigquery.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Below is the big query config am based on the link : [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example)

```
BigQueryOutputConfiguration.configureWithAutoSchema(
      conf,
      outputTableId,
      outputGcsPath,
      BigQueryFileFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
      classOf[TextOutputFormat[_,_]])

    conf.set("mapreduce.job.outputformat.class",
      classOf[IndirectBigQueryOutputFormat[_,_]].getName)

    conf.set(BigQueryConfiguration.OUTPUT_TABLE_WRITE_DISPOSITION_KEY,
      "WRITE_APPEND")
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the data is being read correctly from your cassandra resource (with proper field aliases for each selected column)?

Comment: Yes. If i do a df.show i can see the data.

Comment: Have observed one more thing: while writing the data read from Cassandra into gcs bucket, I don't see data if the output file format is CSV or JSON, but if I write the data into parquet format, the data is available.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error 'No import schema provided, auto detecting schema', it seems that BQ was not able to recognize the schema. Documentation mentions something about this '[BigQuery makes a best-effort](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#schema_auto-detection_for_external_data_sources)'.

In that sense, it should work if you set the schema manually. You can do it with [the method configure](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/bigquery-connector/0.13.1-hadoop3/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/output/BigQueryOutputConfiguration.html#configure-org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.BigQueryTableSchema-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFileFormat-java.lang.Class-) by passing one of these parameters:

- BigQueryTableSchema
- A String in JSON format containing the schema.

In the second link you will see that '[avro stores the schema in the file](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.cloud.bigdataoss/bigquery-connector/0.13.1-hadoop3/com/google/cloud/hadoop/io/bigquery/output/BigQueryOutputConfiguration.html#configure-org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.output.BigQueryTableSchema-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.hadoop.io.bigquery.BigQueryFileFormat-java.lang.Class-)' and most likely that's why the avro file is written in GCS.